# Delete method Rails - No route matches [GET] "/bookmarks/11"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, ruby-on-rails-7

My delete method for bookmarks does not seem to work, is this a problem with rails 7 or am I doing something wrong. It states that there is no Get method. I am using turbo-pack methods vs webpack

below is all relevant documents

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'lists#index'
  resources :lists, except: [:edit, :update] do
    resources :bookmarks, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :bookmarks, only: :destroy
end
```

bookmarks_controller.rb

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: :destroy
  before_action :set_list, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
  end

  def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)
    @bookmark.list = @list
    if @bookmark.save
      redirect_to list_path(@list)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    redirect_to list_path(@bookmark.list), status: :see_other
  end

  private

  def bookmark_params
    params.require(:bookmark).permit(:comment, :movie_id)
  end

  def set_bookmark
    @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<% @list.movies.each do |movie|%>
 <% bookmark = Bookmark.find_by(list: @list, movie: movie)  %>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card text-center text-white" style="background-color:#ffa82e00;">
        <div class="card photo" class="card-img-top">
          <%= image_tag(movie.poster_url, class: "card-img-top" )%>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-dark"><%= movie.title%></h5>
            <p class="card-text text-body"><%= movie.overview %></p>
            <p class="card-text text-body"><%= bookmark.comment%></p>
            <%= link_to "delete", bookmark_path(bookmark), data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure you want to remove #{movie.title} from your #{@list.name} list"}, class: 'text-danger' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Bookmark now", new_list_bookmark_path(@list), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: can you update `bookmark_path(bookmark)` to `bookmark`?
Resource: https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/hotwire-turbo-replacing-rails-ujs

Comment: no that did not work. same error. I changed my routes to the below to get it to work but wanted to know why this is happening and where I am going wrong. ```. Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'lists#index'
  resources :lists, except: [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :bookmarks, only: [:new, :create]
  end
  get 'delete_list/:id', to: 'lists#destroy', as: 'delete_list'
  # get 'delete_bookmarks/:id', to: 'bookmarks#destroy', as: 'delete_bookmark'
  resources :bookmarks, only: :destroy
end```

Comment: Even if you use Hotwire/Turbo I am wondering if you should use `data-turbo-method="delete"` when your code is not enclosed in a Turbo frame. Have you tried with `method: 'delete'` ?

Comment: yes I have tried method delete still. did not work,

Comment: `turbo-pack methods` - by the looks of it, javascript is not set up properly, and you don't have rails' `Turbo` loaded.

Comment: @Alex how do I fix this

Comment: i've never used `turbopack`. besides, you haven't shown anything related to your js setup.  if you don't know, just stick to esbuild or webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `button_to` instead which creates an actual form element and works even without relying on JavaScript:

```erb
<%= button_to "delete", 
               bookmark, 
               data: { 
                turbo_confirm: "Are you sure you want to remove #{movie.title} from your #{@list.name} list"
               }, 
               method: :delete,
               class: 'text-danger' 
%>
```

This has additional benefits to accessibility and the historical reasons why Rails used links and JS to turn clicking a link into a form submission are largely irrelevant in 2023. This is a feature that Turbo just provides for backwards compatibly.

As to why it doesn't work:

- Turbo isn't properly included.
- You have an error in your javascript thats preventing the event handler from doing its job.
- You have a conflicting event handler.
- It's the wrong phase of the planets...

Comment: The reason why `link_to ..., method: :delete` was used is to avoid the overhead provided by having a bunch of form elements on the page and the problems with styling buttom elements cross browser in ye olden days. The only scenario I can think of where it actually has merit today is if you want to add a link inside of form that sends a non-GET request as nested forms are prohibited in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you are using `link_to` which will send a `GET` request. Try using `button_for` instead.

Comment: Yeah but no. If Turbo is properly set up and installed it adds an event handler that turns clicks on elements with `data-turbo-method` into a form submission.